# Why is this a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Assume that for some
$x,y \in G$ if $xy \in H$ then $yx \in H$. Show that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers instead of downvotes if you show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Are you sure you don't mean "for every" where you have written "for some"?

Comment: Let $x \in G$ and $y \in H$. Then $(x^{-1})xy \in H$ and hence by condition given $xyx^{-1} \in H$. Thus $H$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

A subgroup $H$, of group $G$ is normal if $\forall$ $g \in G$ and $\forall h \in H$, $ghg^{-1} \in H$.

Given: for $x,y \in G$ if $xy \in H$ then $yx \in H$.

For any $g \in G$ and $h \in H$, $g^{-1}(gh)= h \in H$. ($h$ trivially $\in G$)

By the given, with $x=g^{-1}$ and $y=gh$, since $xy \in H$, $yx \in H$

$\implies ghg^{-1} \in H$

$\therefore$ $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: This is a correct proof - because you implicitly corrected the OP's mistaken "some" for "every".